# How to set fileformat based on file type?

Tags: autocmd, unix, file-formats

In a project I need to set `fileformat=dos` for all *.html files. Is it possible to do with `autocmd`?

My `fileformats=unix,dos` by default, since I'm on Linux.

I've tried the simplest way:

```
autocmd BufRead *.html setlocal fileformat=dos
autocmd FileType html setlocal fileformat=dos
```

Nothing worked even in this simplified way.

---

What I've been trying to set up is actually this (`s:config` is defined etc.):

```
if has_key(s:config, 'fileformats')
  for key in keys(s:config.fileformats)
    execute ':autocmd FileType ' . key . ' setlocal fileformat=' . s:config.fileformats[key]
  endfor
endif
```

---

After some additional research, I found that `fileformat` is set automatically if `binary` is off, and if all lines end with `\r\n` and `fileformats=unix,dos` (in my case), then it's
set to `dos`, otherwise `unix`. In my case the problem was (and probably is) that a file doesn't have a new line character at the end, that's why `fileformat=unix` always.

---

Currenty I've resorted to manually setting such malformed file to `fileformat=dos`

Could anyone help me please to automate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are in fact 4 different ways to do this. You can read all of them in `:h new-filetype`. I will only describe the simplest solution:

In your user runtime directory, create a new file in your `ftdetect` directory (e.g. `~/.vim/ftdetect`) with the following line (or any other setting you want to apply)

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.html            set fileformat=dos
```

The name of the file is not important. Restart vim, open a new file with .html extension and check that its `fileformat` has been changed successfully.

Comment: Thank you, sorry, I didn't have a chance to try it yet, I hope I'll to in later during the week